# Spring 3 controller exception handler implementation problems 

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I was hoping to implement a single "ExceptionController" to handle exceptions that are thrown in execution of my other controllers' methods. I hadn't specified any HandlerExceptionResolver in my application context so according to the [API documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) the AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver should be started. I verified it as such in the source. So why doesn't the following work?

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController {

  @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
  public ModelAndView handleNullPointerException(NullPointerException ex) {
    // Do some stuff
    log.error(logging stuff)
    return myModelAndView;
  }
}

@Controller
public class AnotherController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/nullpointerpath")
  public String throwNullPointer() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
}
```

I see in the debug logs that the three default exception handlers are asked for handling of the exception, but nothing is done and I see "DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request". Followed by the user being displayed the stacktrace and a 500 Internal error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your Exception handler is returning a view that exists/maps to a handler.

Comment: @predhme, did that really fix your problem? I have an example just like yours, and the @ExceptionHandler method is only invoked when the exception is thrown from the same controller.

Comment: I noticed that later on as well. I guess the most important thing was for me to setup a 500 and 404 pages so that if there was anything I didn't catch, the user wasn't presented with a stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

You should write your exceptionhandler to the same class with which you want to handle, like the following.

```
@Controller
public class AnotherController {
    @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNullPointerException(NullPointerException ex) {
        // Do some stuff.
        log.error(logging stuff)
        return myModelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/nullpointerpath")
    public String throwNullPointer() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good design.  Controllers in Spring handle HTTP requests and map to URLs.  I don't think "exception" fits into either bin.  It feels like a misuse of Spring to me.

An exception is not an HTTP request.  You don't map an exception to a URL.  Therefore I'd conclude that controllers aren't intended to be treated as exception handlers.

Controllers *are* a part of the Spring API, but your design isn't using them as intended, so that's why it's not working.  Re-think your design.

Comment: It's apart of the spring API. Not sure I understand why that it would be misuse then.  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers