# @ResponseStatus and web.xml <error-page>

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml

Here's what i have so far :
controller :

```
public abstract class MyController {
   @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
   public void handleAllExceptions(Exception e) {
      // stuff
   }
}
```

and my web.xml :

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error.htm</location>
</error-page>
```

And when an unexpected exception occur, the handle works, the stuff is done, but i'm not redirect to /error.htm

Instead i'm still on the same page, but a error 500 is printed by apache.

What did i miss ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to return the view you want to show.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String handleAllExceptions(Exception e) {
  return "error.jsp"; /* use the correct view name */
}
```

@see: [Spring 3 controller exception handler implementation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633451/spring-3-controller-exception-handler-implementation-problems)  for some examples

Comment: return "redirect:/error.htm"; with the redirect: it works ! Thanks :)