# Can a Spring MVC exception handler ONLY support return type of type View?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testerror", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public
        @ResponseBody
        ErrorTO testerror(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
           throw new RuntimeException("erorrrrrr");
        }

        @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
        public @ResponseBody ErrorTO handlePoprocksExceptionAsReponseBody(RuntimeException ex,
               HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            response.setStatus(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return new ErrorTO(ex.getMessage(), -999);
        }
```

The above code did not work. StackTrace looked like this:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: erorrrrrr
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

I looked at *[Spring 3 controller exception handler implementation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633451)* , and based on that it seems to be that exception handlers can only return views. Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out to be a bug and said to be fixed in 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to let Spring know how to convert the return Object by you exception handler so it can write to HTTP response.
Lets say "ErrorTO" is a JAXB object and then returned content type is application/xml you should create a HandlerExceptionResolver in your application context and configure a message converter that support application/xml content type (e.g. org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter). here is an example:

```
  <bean id="outboundExceptionAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <util:list>
        <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
      </util:list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.acme" />
  </bean>
```